# jQuery script not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a jQuery script, yet it is not displaying as it should. I have it working [within JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzmtz2f/). Yet it does not work within my page: when an option is chosen it does not show anything at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/faqtest.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('select').on('change',function() {
      var answer = $(this).val();
      $('.answers').hide();
      $('#'+answer).show();
    })
    </script>
    <select>
      <option disabled selected>choose</option>
      <option value="answer1">answer1</option>
      <option value="answer2">answer2</option>
      <option value="answer3">answer3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="answers" id="answer1">answer1</div>
    <div class="answers" id="answer2">answer2</div>
    <div class="answers" id="answer3">answer3</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No select elements created at the time you run the script.

Comment: Put your code inside `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the code on [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function() {
    var answer = $(this).val();
    $('.answers').hide();
    $('#'+answer).show();
  });
});
```